# How to start a new Vala project in MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop, vala

I have Ubuntu 12.04, MonoDevelop 2.8 and some `valac`. I know MD supports Vala language but I don't see any support of Vala there actually. If a C solution is made from scratch, then GCC is used for building the project so the process obviously fails. But there is no an option to choose Vala solution.

Any idea how to start in that environment?

Answer (score 3):

The Vala addin for MonoDevelop is in a separate package.

Comment: This is no longer an option, unfortunately. I have spent a while trying to get the Vala addin for M.D but not a single thing has worked. And according to an answer posted here: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Vala-add-in-for-MonoDevelop-4-0-13-td4661271.html, "Nobody worked on the Vala support for a long time - the core team has a strong c# focus - we're now supporting F# as well.
All other languages need maintainers - and vala currently hasn't one :/"